# ClassCastException using MySQL ReplicationDriver in a JBoss app?

Tags: sql, jboss

Can anyone help me with this? I've read through http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-replication-connection.html and created a JBoss datasource with

```
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql:replication://sys1:3306,sys2:3306,sys3:3306/mydb</connection-url>
<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver</driver-class>
```

In my JBoss code, when I execute the following (on a slave node)

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup( ... );
conn = ds.getConnection();
conn.setReadOnly( false );
conn.prepareStatement( ... );
```

The prepareStatement call produces the following stack trace:

```
2010-09-16 18:45:31,129 WARN  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager] (ajp-127.0.0.1-8009-2) Connection error occured: org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener@1b576f8[state=NORMAL mc=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@11a3ce4 handles=1 lastUse=1284659131129 permit=true trackByTx=false mcp=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$OnePool@193a581 context=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool@56e1fe xaResource=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$LocalXAResource@f058a txSync=null]
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy297
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationConnection.prepareStatement(ReplicationConnection.java:357)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:465)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:460)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:243)
    at com.mycode.service.Kernel.doGet(Kernel.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:384)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've looked around for answers but can't find anyone with a similar problem. Am I missing the obvious???

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We've found the solution !
It's seems, that come from the mysql driver :
The problem occurs with mysql-connector-java-5.1.12 but not with mysql-connector-java-5.1.22.

So, UPGRADE !

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace seems to be suggesting that the ClassCastException is happening in your call to `conn.prepareStatement()` but since you've not copied the arguments into your question I can't tell you what the problem is.